# Caching intermediate result Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Im reading bunch of records from database in the form of RDD and perform different operations. I understand that Spark will release intermediate RDD data after transformation automatically. And it will read it again
from the source, if we refer that intermediate RDD latter part of the program. Does it mean that it will read the data from database again? Anyway tools to advise us which intermediate result should be cached for better result?

Answer (score 1):

Spark is evaluated lazily and the `transformations`(and its output) **won't** materialize until an action is encountered in the `DAG`. Even `persist/cache` is not an `action` and they are lazy too.

If there is an `action` in your DAG till now(the point where you want to access intermediate RDD), plus you have `persist/cache` that precedes the intermediate RDD, spark will recompute only from that action/cached point. Else it will read again from database. If you have no actions and absolutely want to prevent reading database again, you can use `saveAsTextFile()` and read it again.

Comment: Thank you...it helped me to revisit the code base to improve performance.

Comment: One question if I generate intermediate RDD by selecting few rows out of another RDD still I should cache it? Or it is required only when I read data from DB / Files / or any external source?

Comment: which RDD are you going to use again: is it your filtered RDD or the RDD from which you have filtered?

Comment: Ill be using newly created one (filtered RDD).

Comment: You need to persist the filtered RDD. (Assuming you are not going to use parent RDD anymore). You should not read from DB more that once as its going to be a costly operation, you have to create connection object, establish connection etc etc.

Comment: Usually when we work with RDDs we will perform different actions in every step Ex. Adding additional columns based on other column values Or applying list operations like Explode. In this scenario RDD values might change (new columns or column values) in every step. How can I efficiently handle this scenario?

Comment: If `P` is parent RDD & you perform transformations: `T1`)add a column to P `T2`)explode on P `T3`)add column to P `T4`)add column to RESULT OF T2. `T5`) explode on RESULT OF T2. Notice here that you use `P` 3 times & result of transformation `T2` 2 times and `T2` comes from `P`. you need to obviously persist `P`. Now should you persist `T2`?, it depends on multiple factors: 1) if you can hold both P & T2 in memory at a time, persist `T2` too. 2) If you dont have enough memory or `T4` & `T5` is not that time consuming don't persist it. Remember for `T2` spark will start from `P` not from start.

Comment: If I write a statement rdd.cache() it stores it in  node - A memory (RAM) if that data is required by node - B for further process but node - A is busy with other computation it will hit the performance right? What is the design approach I should consider?

Comment: We should not worry about things like this and reinvent the wheel. Let spark handle the situations for you!!. Anyways, to answer your question, at any point of time the whole node isn't going to be utilized for a single computation, a node can further contain multiple executors, which does the actual heavy lifting not the node itself.